# loading pages dynamically and hiding Grid?

Tags: atk4

I have a grid in my page and there is a details button like this:

```
$grid->addColumn('button','tid','Details');
```

I want that after clicking the details button, the grid goes hidden and another view be loaded via AJAX...

Is it possible?

Best regards

Answer (score 0):

### Capturing the click

As you know buttons in ATK Grid by default execute ajaxec() request. They send extra request to the PHP side and then send necessary javascript instructions through jQuery_Chain->execute.

You can also capture the click right away through a technique explained here: http://agiletoolkit.org/codepad/gui/grid

You would also probably need to know that js() can take second argument array of jQuery chains.

More on chains: http://agiletoolkit.org/learn/understand/chains

### Loading information inside View

You can do this in two ways. The first - classical approach where would need to use a selector and load data manually:

```
$b->js('click')->atk4_loader('loadURL',
    array($this->api->url(),'cut_object'=>$b->name,'arg'=>$field->js()->val()));
```

The other approach would be to simply add a blank View, then conditionally load contents inside it:

```
$v=$this->add('View');
if($_GET['details']) {
    $v->add('View_ModelDetails')->setModel('User')->load($_GET['details']);
}
```

Then use

```
$v->js()->reload(array(
    'details'=>$this->js()
         ->_selectorThis()   // targets clicked button
         ->closest('tr')
         ->data('id')        // passes ID of the argument
))
```

Further detailed here: http://agiletoolkit.org/codepad/interaction/reloading

There are quite few steps and you'll need to put them together. Here is another older example which you might be able to adapt:

http://demo39.agiletoolkit.org/demo.html?t=22